# max over PARTITION BY doesn't return with dbms_lob.substr

Tags: sql, oracle, max, window-functions

```
select EVENT_TYPE, dbms_lob.substr( REPLACE(PK_DATA,'"','')) pk
, max(DATA_ID) over 
(PARTITION BY dbms_lob.substr( REPLACE(PK_DATA,'"',''), 100, 1 )) max_data_id
   from(
    select 'U' AS EVENT_TYPE,to_clob(x.ID) AS PK_DATA ,100000 AS DATA_ID 
    from SOME_TABLE where  SOME_CONDITION
UNION ALL
.
.
.
SOME OTHER TABLES
                  );
```

I have this query, it runs forever and doesn't finish.

If I remove `dbms_lob.substr( REPLACE(PK_DATA,'"',''), 100, 1 )` and `to_clob(x.ID)` and replace them by `PK_DATA` and `x.ID` respectively, It's ok

I want to know why is it doing so, given that if I remove this and settle to the other unioned tables (that have the same structure surely), It returns.

Comment: The other unions are also doing `dbms_lob.substr(replace(<clob>, ...`? What data type is `x.id`, and why are you converting it to a CLOB at all if you only want the first 100 characters? How much data is there - does it really never return, or it just taking a long time because of the conversions? Your outer substr doesn't have position or length but that might be a mistake creating the question.

Comment: -other unions are not doing, they are CLOBs , that's why I convert to CLOB .... It really never returns (left it runing for 1 day, though when removed it returned in less than a minute) ....the total of the unions is about 8M .. the substr with no length is a typo as u said

Comment: Doesn't answer why it's struggling, but why aren't you just converting to CLOB in the outer select list, and leaving it as its original type in the inner query and partition clause? I'm not sure if that's what you say is OK, and you're just curious about why it has a problem.

Comment: actually, I did the reverse, I moved dbms_lob.substr( REPLACE(PK_DATA,'"','')) to the unioned tables which return CLOBs